# reading a text file with specfic string

Tags: c#

I want to read a data from 'newline' to 'endline', create a separate file to store this data .
Iwant to repeat this process upto end of file. I am using .net 1.1.

Comment: There is a key called "SPACE" in keyboard, please try using it sometimes

Comment: Hi Maxy, we are glad to help, but getting a full anwer will teach you much less than showing us some code you wrote yourself on which we can comment.

Comment: Is this a 'please do my homework' question. If it's for practicing, then do exactly that. If you're a developer (even a totally unexperienced one), then it is a matter of minutes...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like two nested while loops (one looking for 'newline' and one looking for 'endline') would do the trick.